# Detect sexual content in image and text

Tags: social-networking, image-recognition

I have started a social networking app and there is one user who won't stop uploading images of woman, who, well, are up to some sexual activities. He additionally adds offensive captions to them.

My question: how can I detect adult content in images and text and block them from my app? I think this is a problem that most people face who are making any kind of open networking app. It would be great if the solution was as fast and low-priced as possible.

Comment: You might want to check out Amazon Image Rekognition API - Makes the task pretty easy.

https://aws.amazon.com/rekognition/

Answer (score 0):

1. Implement a system which essentially stores {256-sha image hash, human rating, computer rating} into a database.
2. Create an interface for the human rating and the computer rating which can judge and categorize images as well as an interface in your software which can use that information on how to handle such images.
3. Choose a tool, likely a convolutional neural network based algorithm, with an easy to use api. Here's a random result from searching: https://imagga.com/solutions/adult-content-moderation.html
4. Put everything together and you should have a system which can automatically guess how to handle images, but also allows you to iterate through them which both corrects the database as well as trains the rating algorithm which trains based on the existing human produced data.

Note: The status of an image is not permanent by the software unless a human rates it. Whenever one is accessed, the latest state of the image detection decides on it. If this happens far too frequently to support, then associate a time buffer with the image so that it doesn't re-rate it often.

Update: The advantages of this custom solution is that you can control things to work the way you want. You can define the rating system and how to handle the situation as well as governance over whatever set of trained algorithms you are using. You always have the final say and you can see what is going on at all times. The catch is that you would need to implement this software as an extension to your project.

Answer (score -1):

Not easily, it would require machine learning techniques and a ton of training. Not to mention, all modern techniques can easily be tricked.

There are a few moderation solutions, but they aren't ideal.

First, you could ban them. Not the best, as they could make another account, but it means that they have to make another email for it.

Second, you could isolate him. I forget exactly how it works, but the idea is that they still think that they are posting on your app, but none of their content gets propagated to other people.

I don't know the legality of either of these, its all up to your terms and conditions. But AI is not really a good option, especially if your app were to need to scale.

Comment: This specific idea of "isolation" is called a shadowban.

Comment: Cheers, didn't know how to find that

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yeah, I've already shadow banned him, he thinks he can post but he actually can't make any connections in the app. Right now, I'm doing the app all by myself and I'm experiencing massive growth which is why I can't really keep up with moderating the content ;D